# Proving autocorrelation is periodic for a wide sense stationary

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Let $ \left\{ X\left(t\right)\right\} _{t\in R} $ be a WSS process.

There is a number $T\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $R_X(0)=R_X(T) $ where $R_X$ is the autocorrelation function.
Prove that $R_X$ is a periodic function with period $T$.

My attempt:
$$ 
\require{cancel} R_{X}\left(0\right)=R_{X}\left(t_{i},t_{i}\right)=R_{X}\left(t_{i},t_{i}+T\right)\tag{Given} \\ $$ Now we can multiply both sides by $R_x(t_i)$ $$
R_{X}\left(t_{i},t_{i}\right)\cdot R_{X}\left(t_{i}\right)=R_{X}\left(t_{i},t_{i}+T\right)R_{X}\left(t_{i}\right)\Rightarrow$$
$$ \\
R_{X}\left(t_{i},t_{i}\right)\cdot R_{X}\left(0,t_{i}\right)=R_{X}\left(t_{i},t_{i}+T\right)\cdot R_{X}\left(0,t_{i}\right)\\
\int f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}X\left(t_{i}\right)X\left(t_{i}\right)\int f_{X\left(0\right)}f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}X\left(0\right)X\left(t_{i}\right)=\int f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}f_{X\left(t_{i}+T\right)}X\left(t_{i}\right)X\left(t_{i}+T\right)\int f_{X\left(0\right)}f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}X\left(0\right)X\left(t_{i}\right)\\ $$
Now assuming we can rearenge the 2 integrals on the right we can get: $$
\cancel{\int f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}X\left(t_{i}\right)X\left(t_{i}\right)}\int f_{X\left(0\right)}f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}X\left(0\right)X\left(t_{i}\right)=\int f_{X\left(0\right)}f_{X\left(t_{i}+T\right)}X\left(t_{i}+T\right)X\left(0\right)\cancel{\int f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}X\left(t_{i}\right)f_{X\left(t_{i}\right)}X\left(t_{i}\right)} \Rightarrow R_{X}\left(t_{i}\right)=R_{X}\left(t_{i}+T\right)$$

Is this solution valid, assuming interchanging elements in two integrals are allowed?

Comment: by the definition of weak stationarity, the covariance of a group of observations ( of size n ) should be the same as the  joint density of another group of observations that is shifted over by a fixed amount of time units.  I don't understand your notation as far as $R_{x}(0)$ etc but I think it should be possible to use that property of weak stationarity  to prove the periodicity of the autocorrelation function. Note that an autocorrelation usually has two indices such as R(t,s) which would denote the correlation of $X_t$ and $X_s$. This is why I was confused by your notation.

Comment: For WSS processes $R_X(t_1,t_2)=R_X(0,t_2-t_1) \triangleq R_x(t_2-t_1) $ , so the autocorrelation is a function of the delay between $t_1,t_2 $ only

Comment: Hi Danny. So, the proof becomes pretty straightforward. If $R_x(t_{2} - t_{1}) = R_{x}(0)$, then, let $t_{2} - t_{1} = t^{*}$. Due to WSS, $R_X(2t^{*}) = R_{X}(t^{*})$ so it's periodic.

Comment: why does it mean that $R_X(2t^*)=R_X(t^*) $?
WSS only says that if $R_X(t_1,t_2)=R_X(t_1+\tau , t_2 +\tau ) $ , why does it say anything about the period in this case?

Comment: Danny: It's quite confusing what each assumption assumes. But let's assume for a moment, that the covariance of an observation at time $t$ and an observation at time $s$ is only a function of the time difference $s-t$.  Let me continue this later with a comment below. I've been interrupted by someone.

Comment: using ACov for autocovariance. So,  let $X_{0}$ denote  an observation at time $t = 0$ and and $X_{1}$ denote another one at time $t =T$. We have,that $ACov(X_{0}, X_{1}) = R_{x}(T)$. Now take a third observation $X_{2}$ as the observation at time $t = 2T$. Then, we have that $ACov(X_{1}, X_{2}) = R_{x}(2T - T)$. But, $R_{x}(2T - T) = R_{x}(T)$ which is the covariance of $X_{0}$ and $X_{1}$. So,  $ACov(X_{1}, X_{2}) = R_{x}(T)$ again. So, we have shown that the auto- covariance between $X_{0}$ and  $X_{1}$ equals the auto-covariance between $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ so we have the periodicity.

Comment: I hope the above makes sense. I used autocovariance instead of autocorrelation but they are just scale factors of each other so that's not important.

Comment: I think I understand now, tyvm!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. The autocovariance is an expectation of two random variables so the term "auto" in auto-covariance is really referring to the fact that the 2 variables come from the same underlying distribution. But there are still two of them. Earlier today, I was thinking that it was best to think of auto-covariance as having to do with one RV. But I deleted that comment because it's not the correct way to think about auto-covariance. All the best.